# Xamarin.Forms default navigation bar font

Tags: xamarin, fonts, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms I have created a custom Navigation bar using a `StackLayout` and `Labels` for one of my pages. The other pages however are using the default navigation bar. I've tried to make the titles of the custom and default navigation bars look exactly the same but can't quite get it to match.

Is there a way to find out the font size and family of the default navigation bar in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is! Xamarin.Forms is fully open-source, so you can inspect anything the code is doing [on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms). The magic most likely happens inside the `NavigationPage` renderers, so check out `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.[Target Platform]/Renderers/NavigationPageRenderer.cs`.

But in your case this might be overkill, and you might be able to get the information you are interested in [using the Xamarin Inspector](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/inspector/) while your app is running in debug mode.

Comment: I didn't find anything related to the navigation bar fontsize and fontfamily attritubutes in the NavigationPageRenderer.cs. And I don't have Visual Studio Enterprise Edition to use the Xamarin Inspector.